# How to fetch "ME" (Owner Profile) profile data from contact list?

Tags: android

My requirement is only to get the "ME" profile info from android. Is it possible? Please tell me if you know.

Comment: What is `ME`? Explain your problem .

Comment: @ADM I think they need to get contact info about user owning the phone, which is labelled as 'Me' in contacts app.

Comment: Any number can labeled is `Me` in contacts . Thats not a standard protocol to get the owner info. I think getting the accounts can be a better way .

Comment: ME means owner profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Me contact in Android is handled using [ContactsContract.Profile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile) Added in API 14 .

You can find how to retrieve basic details in the query below

```
String[] PROJECTION = {
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_URI,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE
    };
```

---

```
final ContentResolver content = context.getContentResolver();
final Cursor cursor = content.query(
        // Retrieves data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact
        Uri.withAppendedPath(
                             ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                             ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
                             PROJECTION,

                             // Selects only email addresses or names
                             ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR "
                             + ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR "
                             + ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR "
                             + ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                             new String[]{
                                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                             },

                             // Show primary rows first. Note that there won't be a primary email address if the
                             // user hasn't specified one.
                             ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC"
);
```

To get information you need to go through your cursor

```
String mime_type;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        mime_type = cursor.getString(7); // 7 is for index based on previous projection
        if (mime_type.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
            String email = cursor.getString(/** use email index from projection*/);
        else if (mime_type.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
            /** Retrieve information from cursor based on your index*/
        else if (mime_type.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
            /** Retrieve information from cursor based on your index*/
        else if (mime_type.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
            /** Retrieve information from cursor based on your index*/
    }
```

Otherwise you can also about using [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager) to get information about the user's account

Comment: which error are you getting? you have a user profile already on your device?

Comment: I got the name only. Can you please explain the way you fetch this info from the cursor.

Comment: check updated answer.. you just need to go through your cursor and check based on the data's mimetype. then you'll get all available information (if profile have them of course)